# How to generate particle positions from probability density function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, sampling

I have a two-dimensional probability density field $f(x,y)$ with
$$\int \int f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=1$$
And I would like to generate particles from that probability density field but I am not sure how to realize that computational wise.

My idea is to randomly choose a point $x_{i},y_{j}$ in the domain, and then create another uniformly random number $c$ between 0 and 1 and if that number is higher than the probability at that point $f(x_{i},y_{j})<c$, then I save this point as a particle location.
But the results I obtain with this aren't as good.
Is there a better way to do this?
And does there exist a a technical term under which I can find literature about these kind of problems or methods?

Comment: This is done by the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm.

Comment: The method you are using is called the "rejection method", googling will show you the tricks and gotchas.

Comment: In your case "generating particles" means "pseudorandom variate generation." Good solid literature on the subject, have a look.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick replies!